# Magento 2.2 - It is possible to change the font on the Magento Admin?

Tags: magento2, theme, fonts, font-family

Do we need any themes or we can change the font from the existing Magento files as we change the fonts on the frontend?

Comment: Please follow this link,
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-change-default-icon-for-top-level-menu-backend-in-magento-2.html

Comment: Thank you so much! Already reviewed this link, any other reference with exact examples?